# How do I add custom keybindings in spacemacs?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, config

I want to bind `Ctlr+s` to "save current buffer" (currently `SPC f s`). How can I do this?

When I search online, I find many complicated explanations of how to do very specific things, like how to bind keys in a certain mode or for a certain file type. It also seems like just binding them normally doesn't work, because the vim keys that spacemacs comes with override it.

Moreover, the default `init.el` file is very complex (580 lines) so I don't know where I would be putting the keybindings either. I'm hoping there's a place in it where I can put something like `source keybindings.el` and then put all of my bindings in `keybindings.el`, but I can't tell where or how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For spacemacs, the canonical way to make small modification as such is to put your configs inside the `defun` of `dotspacemacs/user-config` inside `~/.spacemacs` file.

If this is the first time you make modifications to this function, it should look like this:

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration function for user code.
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs initialization after
layers configuration.
This is the place where most of your configurations should be done. Unless it is
explicitly specified that a variable should be set before a package is loaded,
you should place your code here."
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-s") #'save-buffer)
  (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-s") #'save-buffer))
```

Make sure you quit and restart emacs (server or daemon if you uses them) for this to work (Note that closing the emacsclient frame might not be sufficient if your setting allows the daemon/server to persist in background. Use <kbd>SPC q q</kbd> for a full restart). In this case, manually evaluate those `define-key` expressions will also work for your current session.

But you want to put them inside another file, so please continue your reading.

---

Explanation:

For most cases in spacemacs when you are inside an actual file where you would want to save, `evil-mode` is activated for sure. That why if you follow certain tutorial online, where you might be told to modify <kbd>C-s</kbd> inside `global-map`, it might not work especially if you are in `evil-normal-state`. That's because `evil-mode` is a minor mode, whose keymap has higher priority than `global-map`.

The above 2 `define-key` expressions set <kbd>C-s</kbd> in `normal` and `insert` state of `evil-mode` to command `save-buffer`, which should be enough for most of your cases.

---

For spacemacs, `~/.emacs.d/init.el` belongs to spacemacs itself, thus you should not touch it.

---

If you wanna do something like `source keybindings.el`, you would most likely do the following (`dotspacemacs/user-config` is a good place to put these two lines):

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration function for user code.
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs initialization after
layers configuration.
This is the place where most of your configurations should be done. Unless it is
explicitly specified that a variable should be set before a package is loaded,
you should place your code here."
  (add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/dir")  ;;; which contains `keybindings.el'
  (load "keybindings"))
```

where `keybindings.el` should contain the above two `define-key` expressions.

(NOTE: Other common methods like `require` together with `provide` requires more elisp knowledge at this time and please refer to the manual.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! However, after putting those two `define-key` exprs in my user config block (in `~/.spacemacs.d/init.el`), Ctrl+s still does an incremental search instead of saving.

Comment: @Jessica It works for me. What does it output when you do the following in a file you've opened?  1. In `evil-normal-state`, do `C-h k C-s` ?  2. What about in `evil-insert-state` ?

Comment: Both show me the help page for `isearch-forward`.

Comment: @Jessica I see. We've got some differences in our settings. Could you elaborate some more for me, please? 1. Are you using helm or ivy? 2. In the help page, which keymap does it say `C-s` is coming from? (i.e. as in the phrase (found in ....-map))?

Comment: 1. I think it's helm, but how do I tell? 2. I get `(found in global-map)`.

Comment: @Jessica Wow, that's weird. I think in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`, if you specify ivy, you are using ivy; otherwise it defaults to helm. That's okay. The weird part is that it says `C-s` activates global-map, which has the lowest precedence. It seems to me that your 2 `define-key` exprs does not get loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137249/discussion-between-terrytsao-and-jessica).